# Setup de programa en visual studio

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando realizar un instalado de mi proyecto, pero al intentar instalarlo me dice que ocupo el framework .NET 4.6.1, me pregunta que si deseo descargalo, de digo que si, me descarga el framework 4.6.1 y al intentar instalarlo dice que ya tengo una version mas reciente instalada. En resumen no puedo usar mi Setup.

¿Como puedo resolver el problema o generar el Setup de otra manera?

Nota: En el proyecto tengo descargado un paquete NuGet de sqlite

Comment: Entiendo que es un proyecto que has hecho tu, entonces tal vez puedes cambiar las condiciones de inicio del proyecto y poner un framework distinto al que hay actualmente y que coincida con el que tienes instalado en la máquina de instalación.

Comment: Use una herramienta de VS para generar el Setup, en la cual no me da opcion de cambiar el framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Abre el instalador de Visual Studio.
2. Dale click en modificar la instalación actual de VS.
3. Dale click a la pestaña de instalación de componentes individuales.
4. Selecciona los sdks que necesitas con su respectivo "Targeting Pack".
5. Dale click en modificar.